# Group value for column given other column

Tags: r

I want to count the value of column 1 for each value in column2

I looked at `group_by`, `summarize` and `sum` but I don't get the hang of it.

I tried for example:

```
df <- data0 %>%
group_by(Room) %>%
summarize(count = n()) %>% 
mutate(Timespend = sum(Time))
```

The summarize is to see how many times a room is used. Now I would like to see Room X is used 100 times (this I have) for a total time of 300 hours

Example:

```
Activity Room Time Date
Math     C123 3.50 2019/10/10
Physics  C123 1.5  2019/10/10
English  C123 2.5  2019/10/11 
Math     C124 3.20 2019/10/10
Physics  C124 2.5  2019/10/10
English  C124 1.5  2019/10/11
```

All activities happen in room C123 and C124 and I would like to see the total time activity has taken place in a given room

So something like this:

```
Room Count Timespend
C123 3     7.5
C124 3     7.2
```

Ther are of course more rooms and more dates, but this sample gives the essence.

Dput:

```
structure(list(Activity = c("Math", "Physics", "English", "Math", 
"Physics", "English"), Room = c("C123", "C123", "C123", "C124", 
"C124", "C124"), Time = c(3.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.2, 2.5, 1.5), Date = structure(c(1570665600, 
1570665600, 1570752000, 1570665600, 1570665600, 1570752000), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: shouldn't it be 7.5 and 7.2?

Comment: Are you looking for `df %>% group_by(Room) %>% summarise(Count = n(), Timespend = sum(Time))` ?

Comment: @StupidWolf Yes, it should.

Comment: @dc37 I updated the code I tried, with variable names from the example

Comment: You can do this all with `group_by` and `summarise`: `data0 %>%
  group_by(Room) %>% summarise(Timespend = sum(Time), Count = n())`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df <- data0 %>% group_by(room) %>% 
  mutate(Timespend = sum(Tdiff),
         n = 1:n()) %>%
  filter(n == 1)
```